# Including MSSQL Server Analysis in WebDev Setup Disk

Tags: sql-server

Hi All and thanks in advance.

I have an application developed in WebDev 22, and I was able to successfully upload it to my own personal Home Web server, The Application works fine however it cannot read the data because it does not have the analysis.

This application Analysis uses an MSSQL Server Database via the Analysis utilizing MSQL Server Machine ODBC (Means that I am not using the PCSoft Native MS SQL Drivers).

How can place the analysis when creating the Deployment Setup Install File, and how to configure it so that when I am installing the Application in the Site it will talk to the same database I have installed on the Windows Web Server at Home?

Does anyone knows, can this be possible?

Thanks
Regards,

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own situation resolved.

It turns out that when a Setup Disk is created in PC Soft WebDev, it will automatically include the Database analysis inside the package, in my case I used the option of creating a Media Setup disk to run it in the Web Server, and install the application there. I thought that a very special configuration was needed to be done to connect the Analysis to the MS SQL Data Server in the Web Server, and is none of that.

Let me explain how I got it solved and I would like to explain that everything
was done in the Analysis connection to make possible this connection.

1. Open the Analysis and Click Connections.
2. These are the Parameter:

   **Name: Your Connection Name.**

   **Caption: Your Connection Name here if you want.**

   **Connection By: SQL Server (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server).**

   **Data Source: Your MSSQL Database Server Name.**

   **Database: Your Database Name.**

   **User Name: User you created to connect to this database.**

   **Password: The User Password for the User.**
3. Click on Test, if the Connection is successful you are good to Go.
   **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE VISUAL ON THE SERVER YOU ARE TRYING TO CONNECT**
4. Save the Analysis and Synchronize.
5. Create the Setup disk and install on the Web Server.
6. That is it.!!

   **Why?**

Because of when the WebDev application starts, it will **Automatically** open the Analysis.
The Analysis will then automatically look at the settings you have provided in the Analysis Connection Settings, and it makes the connection.

That is it, I hope this has help.

Best regards,

Carlos